# Table posts for model Post was not found in datasource default?

Tags: cakephp, phpmyadmin

Trying to learn CakePHP I completed the [Blog Tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html) without issue.
The browser shows the Cake welcome page, the database connection file is found, and Cake successfully connects to the database.
The only thing I did differently is that I used phpMyAdmin to create the `posts` table in a database named `default,` but with all of the same content as in the tutorial.
Why do I get

> Error: Table posts for model Post was not found in datasource default.

in the [Blog Tutorial - Adding a layer](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html)? 
This is the Model:

```
<?php
class Post extends AppModel {
}
```

This is the Controller:

```
<?php
class PostsController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
    public function index() {
        $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
    }
}
```

This is the View:

```
<!-- File: /app/View/Posts/index.ctp -->    
<h1>Blog posts</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Created</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $post['Post']['id']; ?></td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link($post['Post']['title'],
array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view', $post['Post']['id'])); ?>
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $post['Post']['created']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php unset($post); ?>
</table>
```

And this is the Stack Trace:

```
CORE\Cake\Model\Model.php line 3243 → Model->setSource(string)
CORE\Cake\Model\Model.php line 2696 → Model->getDataSource()
APP\Controller\PostsController.php line 5 → Model->find(string)
[internal function] → PostsController->index()
CORE\Cake\Controller\Controller.php line 486 → ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(PostsController, array)
CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php line 187 → Controller->invokeAction(CakeRequest)
CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php line 162 → Dispatcher->_invoke(PostsController, CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
APP\webroot\index.php line 111 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
```

Comment: Code seems ok. Double check your `database.php` to make correct db name is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code seems ok. Check `database.php` to make sure db name is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Put in the Model

```
<?php
class Post extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Post';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your database user has select permission on the tables.  I had same error and that was my problem.